# Embedded Jetty : setting Protocol Version on a HttpServletRequest

Tags: http, jetty, factory, connector

In my application I have HTTP clients connecting to an embedded Jetty server, and during the communication between the server and the http client there is the need to change the Protocol Version to something different than http 1.1. How can this be achieved?

I am thus looking for the equivalent of getHttpVersion() on the HttpServletRequest. The content exchanged between the client and the server is plain vanilla HTTP, the only thing that has to change is the protocol version, e.g. it has to become some application defined string, different from HTTP x.y or anything that can be achieved through protocol Upgrades.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  A new network protocol? (one that you connect with? or one that you have to upgrade to after connecting with HTTP/1.1?) or just change a version string that everything sees?  Is this an existing protocol on ietf.org?

Comment: It involves Apple's Home Automation Protocol specification. In that spec the HTTP connection between a client and server can be used for an eventing mechanism, where events are exchanged between the client and server. It follows "standard" HTTP, except for the fact that - when an event is sent - the version string is set to something specific. In that sense, it is not a "regular" upgrade of the HTTP protocol, but rather a "hijack"/out-of-band communication as defined by Apple's HAP.

Comment: My initial though was to write an extension of HttpConnection, and override newHttpGenerator() with a custom HttpGenerator (which is most probably a copy/past from Jetty's HttpGenerator except for that fact that generateResponse() might use a different generateResponseLine() in function of the presence of a to-be-defined X-... Header. I would set that Header in the Handler/Servlet's doHandle() whenever the protocol has to be "switched"

Comment: If you are talking about HAP, then that's just JSON to a standard HTTP server, no special HTTP Request Line Version manipulation.  If this is something else, then stackoverflow is not an appropriate place to discuss this (it's too open ended).  If this is the later case, please start a conversation on the [jetty-users mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/jetty-users), we can help, and have a technical conversation around possible ways for you to implement it.

Comment: Indeed HAP is Json and that is rather straight forward. The spec also states: “ The accessory delivers notifications by sending an event message, which is an unsolicited HTTP response, over the TCP connection established by the controller. An event message has the same format as an HTTP response, but uses an protocol version of EVENT/1.0. Event messages must never interrupt a response that is already being sent.”

Comment: That would be modifying the HTTP/1.1 Response Status Line's HTTP Version indicator then.   Has nothing to do with the HttpServletRequest.  Please use jetty-users, stackoverflow is not appropriate for back and forth conversations.